# TypeError: long() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'

Tags: python, tensorflow, command-line, object-detection

I've been following this tutorial that teaches you how to build a program that recognises objects in a video from your webcam using TensorFlow Object Recognition https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MyAOtvwTkT0

My code throws this error:

```
Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "detecting_image_from_vids.py", line 135, in <module>
    feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 889, in run
run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1089, in _run
    np_val = np.asarray(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 531, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
TypeError: long() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

**Question:** Can anyone help me decipher it?

This is the code that I'm trying to run:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import six.moves.urllib as urllib
import sys
import tarfile
import tensorflow as tf
import zipfile

from collections import defaultdict
from io import StringIO
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

# This is needed since the notebook is stored in the object_detection folder.
sys.path.append("..")


# ## Object detection imports
# Here are the imports from the object detection module.

# In[3]:

from utils import label_map_util

from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util


# # Model preparation 

# ## Variables
# 
# Any model exported using the `export_inference_graph.py` tool can be loaded here simply by changing `PATH_TO_CKPT` to point to a new .pb file.  
# 
# By default we use an "SSD with Mobilenet" model here. See the [detection model zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md) for a list of other models that can be run out-of-the-box with varying speeds and accuracies.

# In[4]:

# What model to download.
MODEL_NAME = 'ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_11_06_2017'
MODEL_FILE = MODEL_NAME + '.tar.gz'
DOWNLOAD_BASE = 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/'

# Path to frozen detection graph. This is the actual model that is used for the object detection.
PATH_TO_CKPT = MODEL_NAME + '/frozen_inference_graph.pb'

# List of the strings that is used to add correct label for each box.
PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join('data', 'mscoco_label_map.pbtxt')

NUM_CLASSES = 90


# ## Download Model

# In[5]:

opener = urllib.request.URLopener()
opener.retrieve(DOWNLOAD_BASE + MODEL_FILE, MODEL_FILE)
tar_file = tarfile.open(MODEL_FILE)
for file in tar_file.getmembers():
  file_name = os.path.basename(file.name)
  if 'frozen_inference_graph.pb' in file_name:
    tar_file.extract(file, os.getcwd())


# ## Load a (frozen) Tensorflow model into memory.

# In[6]:

detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
  od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
  with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
    serialized_graph = fid.read()
    od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
    tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')


# ## Loading label map
# Label maps map indices to category names, so that when our convolution network predicts `5`, we know that this corresponds to `airplane`.  Here we use internal utility functions, but anything that returns a dictionary mapping integers to appropriate string labels would be fine

# In[7]:

label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, use_display_name=True)
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)


# ## Helper code

# In[8]:

def load_image_into_numpy_array(image):
  (im_width, im_height) = image.size
  return np.array(image.getdata()).reshape(
      (im_height, im_width, 3)).astype(np.uint8)


# # Detection

# In[9]:

# For the sake of simplicity we will use only 2 images:
# image1.jpg
# image2.jpg
# If you want to test the code with your images, just add path to the images to the TEST_IMAGE_PATHS.
PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR = 'test_images'
TEST_IMAGE_PATHS = [ os.path.join(PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR, 'image{}.jpg'.format(i)) for i in range(1, 3) ]

# Size, in inches, of the output images.
IMAGE_SIZE = (12, 8)


# In[10]:

with detection_graph.as_default():
  with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
    while True:
      ret, image_np = cap.read()
      # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
      image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
      image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
      # Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected.
      boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
      # Each score represent how level of confidence for each of the objects.
      # Score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
      scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
      classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
      num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
      # Actual detection.
      (boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run(
          [boxes, scores, classes, num_detections],
          feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
      # Visualization of the results of a detection.
      vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
          image_np,
          np.squeeze(boxes),
          np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
          np.squeeze(scores),
          category_index,
          use_normalized_coordinates=True,
          line_thickness=8)

      cv2.imshow('object detection', cv2.resize(image_np, (800,600)))
      if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Comment: The error by itself doesn't tell us enough.  Show us your code which produces this error.

Comment: I second @John Gordon's comment. Also, the bit about the CPU isn't too important or related to the error. It just means that your CPU supports newer (faster) instructions than your version of TensorFlow was designed to use. For the kinds of vectorized operations TensorFlow is typically used for, you should get around a 4x or 8x speedup by using the proper binary, depending on your application.

Answer (score 1):

You are using your laptop webcam or external webcam?

If you are using the laptop webcam then:

Change the code:

`cam=cv2.VideoCapture(1)`

to:

`cam=cv2.VideoCapture(0)`

or if you are capturing the frames from another video, pass the path of that video.

Now, coming to the error which you are getting:

`TypeError: In python TypeError is an exception, encountered when you pass an inappropriate object inside a fuction, operate on inappropriate object.`

Here, you are getting this error because,as sess.run() functions,take 4 arguments:

`sess.run(fetches,feed_dict,options,run_metadata)`

Args List Description:

`fetches: You can pass a single graph element, a list of graph elements, or a dictionary whose values are graph elements or lists of graph elements (described above).`

`feed_dict: Takes a dictionary that maps graph elements to values (described above).`

`options: A [RunOptions] protocol buffer`

`run_metadata: A [RunMetadata] protocol buffer`

Returns:

`Either a single value if fetches is a single graph element, or a list of values if fetches is a list, or a dictionary with the same keys as fetches if that is a dictionary (described above).`

Types of Errors/Exceptions which can be generated are:

```
RuntimeError: If this Session is in an invalid state (e.g. has been closed).

TypeError: If fetches or feed_dict keys are of an inappropriate type.

ValueError: If fetches or feed_dict keys are invalid or refer to a Tensor that doesn't exist.
```

In your case TypeError is generated, and error also states that:

`long() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'`
means one of the arguments of `feed_dict={image_tensor:image_np_expanded}
has value NoneType.`

Now, you can debug your program to check this,

Simply check what is datatype of `image_np`, when you are reading the video stream frame by frame by using `cap.read()`, because `cap.read()` returns `true` when it retrieves frame, otherwise it returns `false`.

Accordingly, when

`ret = false; datatype(image_np)=NonType`

`ret = true; datatype(image_np)=ndarray`

Refer the following code, solves your problem:

```
with detection_graph.as_default():
with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
while (cap.isOpened()):
# Defined two variables ret,frame, ret->boolean,checking whether any valueis returned or not from cap.read()
# image_np variable stores each frame which is returned from the func, if no frame is returned,error will not be generated rather it will store NoneType
    ret,image_np=cap.read()
    if ret == True:
        # Definite input and output Tensors for detection_graph
        image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
        image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
        # Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected.
        detection_boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
        # Each score represent how level of confidence for each of the objects.
        # Score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
        detection_scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
        detection_classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
        num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
        # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
        # Actual detection.
        # Syntax of sess.run(fetches,feed_dict,options,run_metadata)
        (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
            [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],feed_dict = {image_tensor:image_np_expanded})
        ### CWH: below is used for visualizing with Matplot
        # Visualization of the results of a detection.
        vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
            image_np,
            np.squeeze(boxes),
            np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
            np.squeeze(scores),
            category_index,
            use_normalized_coordinates=True,
            line_thickness=3)

        cv.imshow('Object Detection Live', cv.resize(image_np , (800,600)))
        # This statemenet runs one time for every frame, and it says that if the user enters 'q', then simply break the loop.
        if ((cv.waitKey(25) & 0xFF) == ord('q')):
            cap.release() #releases the webcam
            cv.destroyAllWindows() #close all imshow() windows
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue for me was sometimes the video stream yielded nothing in which case the result of the line :

```
ret, image_np = cap.read()
```

will yield `ret` will be false.

My fix was to do `if ret == True;` then run inference